# How to create new form on wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create new form on wordoress admin panel for store data by admin, for example i have one student detail and i want store through admin panel.

Please let me know.....

Best
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a new post type? http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

You can set this to not show publicly. You could some something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'acme_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```